# HTML DropDown menu, force URL to open outside of the iframe

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function goToPage(url)
 {
 if (url != "")
 {
 .open(url);
 }
 }
</script>
</head>
<center>
<h2>This feature is coming soon</h2>
<form name="jump">
<p align="center">
<select name="menu">
<option value="URL">*New Offers*</option>
<option value="URL">100% Free Surveys</option>
<option value="URL">*CPM*</option>
<option value="URL">*CPC*</option>
<option value="URL">UK Offers</option>
<option value="URL">AU Offers</option>
<option value="URL">CA Offers</option>
<option value="URL">International Offers</option>
<option value="URL">GPT/PTS/PTC</option>
<option value="URL">1st Page/Email Submits</option>
<option value="URL">1ClickFamily</option>
<option value="URL">Registration Offers</option>
<option value="URL">Downloads</option>
<option value="URL">Purchases/Trials</option>
<option value="URL">Daily Surveys</option>
<option value="URL">Absolute Rewards</option>
<option value="URL">Weekly Surveys</option>
<option value="URL">Survey Panels</option>
<option value="URL">Mobile/Pin Submits</option>
<option value="URL">WinningSurveys</option>
<option value="URL">Monthly Surveys</option>
<option value="URL">Insurance Quotes</option>
<option value="URL">ZZZQuiz</option>
<option value="URL">*Content Unlocker</option>



</select>
<input type="button" onClick="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
</p>
</form>
</center>
</html>
```

Hello, I have created a dropdown menu which will be in an iframe on every page of my website. How can I make the link open in the main window rather than the iframe? for example, in an ordinary text link you would use target='_parent'... what similar function can I use in this script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. If you can, it will violate the iFrame specifications. Since IFrames can be cross domain allowing IFrame to control other windows (main window) in this case is simply - cross-site... If someone find you an hack. I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

You would use Javascript

```
function goToPage(url) {
    document.location=url;
}
```

Good luck!

Let me explain.  You create this function within your "Parent" page and call it from your iFrame.  This make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 function openInParent(url)
 {
  window.parent.parent.window.location = url;
 }
</script>

<input type="button" onClick="openInParent(document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value);" value="GO">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the previous answer...

I've had an application that had multiple iframes that needed to react to actions occurring within the other iframe, including clicking in one iframe resulting in another iframe loading a different page, just as you require.

In my case, I had a parent document with 2 iframes. In one iframe, I had onclick set to call a function on the parent page, and then that function on the parent page would change the contents of the target iframe.

If you are dealing with just one page and one iframe, then you can simply move your GoToURL function to the main page (the parent), and call that function from your iframe (parent.GoToURL(whatever);). That way you'll be able to navigate to other pages based on the actions within that iframe.